# the way to make a picture rotate slowly in html?

Tags: html, css

I am new to html and css code, I am reading the source code of the http://www.quarryequipments.com/products/crusher/pe-jaw-crusher.html ,look at the facebook logo int the bottom  if I put the mouse in it ,it will rotate slowly, how can I  achieve that cool things?

Thanks.

Comment: Em, I am new to html, but was told I can use F12 in Chrome last night to learn how to see the code in html.Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have  a look here.

http://daneden.me/animate/

That site you refrenced was using

```
.end-public a:hover img {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
 -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
 -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
 -o-transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

Comment: I am amused when people write `-ms-transition`, as it has never existed =D

Comment: LOL. -ms-transition cant even google it. I just inspected the element to be honest. so that css class is not my own. just a refrence :p

Comment: I know, it wasn't a comment against you. Just saying, I've seen it around so often... just more proof that people don't really know what they're doing!

Comment: Edited and removed :) thanks for the syntax spotting

Comment: `-ms-transform` does exist, though. IE9 uses it.

Answer (score 4):

That's simple CSS:

```css
.end_public a:hover img {
    transform:rotate(45deg);
    transition-duration:1s;
}
```